# "Delete answer" option in the 10k queue doesn't show amount of deletevotes left

Tags: bug, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

I believe this picture explains it all:

> [image]

When using the "delete" option under a post in the 10k queue, I can see how many deletevotes I have left. However, when using the big black button that says "delete answer" next to the "flag or disagree" button, it's not there! :(

Comment: Clearly because the button was intended for moderators who don't have a limit. This is just to reinforce that you are a mortal! Mwuahahahaha.